# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'url'

Tags: flask, jinja2

This may sound a redundant question but none of the previous solutions work for me. I am new in flask. So may be, something hiding in the plain sight that I am not seeing. Please help me out.

In my base template(baseLayout.html), I have added a nav bar(usying bootstrap styling). It worked well until, I updated my href to -

```
<li class="nav-item ml-md-5">
    <a href="{% url 'taskManager-home' %}" class="nav-link">Home</a>
```

It is showing me a huge list of error statements but the last of all was -

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'url'.
```

Please help me out here.

Comment: Try `url_for('taskManager.home')` (or some variant of that, depending on your code).

Comment: nop, same error- jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'url_for'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get URL from Flask method, `url_for` should be used in templates. Details documentation for `url_for` can be found in [official documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for).

Here I am showing an example of using Bootstrap Navbar and `url_for` for dynamic routing using Flask.

Directory structure:

```
.
├── app.py
├── requirements.txt
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def view_home():
    return render_template("index.html", title="Home page")

@app.route("/first")
def view_first_page():
    return render_template("index.html", title="First page")

@app.route("/second")
def view_second_page():
    return render_template("index.html", title="Second page")
```

`index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Navbar Using Flask</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('view_home') }}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('view_first_page') }}">First Page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('view_second_page') }}">Second Page</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4">
        {% if title %}
          {{ title }}
        {% else %}
        Default title
        {% endif %}
        </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Screenshot:**

1. Home page:

[image: home page]

2. Second page:

[image: second page]

Installed packages (`requirements.txt`):

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.1.1
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==0.16.0
```